# JSON data into csv by using python maybe pandas specific format

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-science

the goal is to convert the given JSON into the CSV data Frame according to the below sample output. this is a part of the whole project. anyone would like to exercise.

**response.json**

```
[
    {
      
      "fiscalPeriodYearMonth": "2012-09",
      
      "revenuePer": {
        "yearOverYear": 19.57,
        "threeYearAvg": 28.24,
        "fiveYearAvg": 21.240000000000002,
        "tenYearAvg": 28.96
      },
      "operatingIncome": {
        "yearOverYear": 21.57,
        "threeYearAvg": 50.019999999999996,
        "fiveYearAvg": 30.3,
        "tenYearAvg": null
      },
      "netIncomePer": {
        "yearOverYear": 14.000000000000002,
        "threeYearAvg": 44.330000000000005,
        "fiveYearAvg": 29.01,
        "tenYearAvg": null
      },
      "epsPer": {
        "yearOverYear": 16.55,
        "threeYearAvg": 44.65,
        "fiveYearAvg": 30.830000000000002,
        "tenYearAvg": null
        }
    },

    {
     
      "fiscalPeriodYearMonth": "2013-09",
      "revenuePer": {
        "yearOverYear": 7.5600000000000005,
        "threeYearAvg": 18.87,
        "fiveYearAvg": 17.9,
        "tenYearAvg": 29.020000000000003
      },
      "operatingIncome": {
        "yearOverYear": 1.06,
        "threeYearAvg": 23.27,
        "fiveYearAvg": 34.11,
        "tenYearAvg": 58.93000000000001
      },
      "netIncomePer": {
        "yearOverYear": 0.77,
        "threeYearAvg": 22.42,
        "fiveYearAvg": 30.12,
        "tenYearAvg": 52.459999999999994
      },
      "epsPer": {
        "yearOverYear": 1.4500000000000002,
        "threeYearAvg": 23.46,
        "fiveYearAvg": 31.5,
        "tenYearAvg": 47.88
      }
    }
  
  ]
```

**My Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(r'PATH TO JSON FILE', orient ='values')

print(df.T.to_csv("final_output.csv"))
```

But it does not giving me the desired following format.

**Output I need**

|  | 2012-09 | 2013-09 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Revenue |  |  |
| Year Over Year | 19.57 | 7.56 |
| 3-Year Average | 28.24 | 18.87 |
| 5-Year Average | 21.24 | 17.90 |
| 10-Year Average | 28.96 | 29.02 |
|  |  |  |
| operatingIncome |  |  |
| Year Over Year | 21.57 | 1.06 |
| 3-Year Average | 50.02 | 23.27 |
| 5-Year Average | 30.30 | 34.11 |
| 10-Year Average | - | 58.93 |

and so on.

I know its a bit logical but very interesting, and will be so easy for someone good in python pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used python pandas before, so I wrote it without it (the only import is a built-in module):

```
import json

with open("test.json") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())


keys = []

isFirst = True

i = 0

for entry in data:
    j = 0
    arrayIndex = 0
    for key in list(entry.keys()):
        
        if isFirst:
            keys.append([key])
        arrayIndex += 1
        if type(data[i][key]) == dict:
            for innerKey in data[i][key]:
                if isFirst:
                    keys.append([innerKey])

                this_data = data[i][key][innerKey]
                if type(this_data) == float:
                    this_data = round(this_data, 2)
                elif type(this_data) == None:
                    this_data = "-"
                keys[arrayIndex].append(this_data)
                arrayIndex += 1
                
        else:
            keys[j].append(entry[key])
        j += 1

    isFirst = False
    i += 1

output = ""
for i in keys:
    for j in i:
        output += str(j) + ","
    output = output[:-1]
    output += "\n"
output = output[:-1]

f = open("output.csv", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

It's a lot longer, but it does work

Comment: Woo it works ! You have made a great algorithm. I will understand my self on it. thanks for your efforts & time.